# Dreamweaver CS5 - See what error is in PHP?

Tags: error-handling, adobe, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

I noticed in Dreamweaver CS5, that when I edit a PHP file and an error is produced, while it highlights the line, I cannot find a way to get the actual error itself like you get in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Dreamweaver only tells you that the syntax is currently invalid.  It doesn't report the actual error.